# Single MySQL Insert with PHP is inputting multiple Records

Tags: php, database, oop

New to OOP with PHP, a bit lost, thanks in advance.

Issue I am having is that when I create a New User, it is inserting 5 records for the same user (new unique primary ID for each). Found lots of issue with people trying to learn to insert multiple records, but think this is the first issue posted on here about multiple records inserting into MySQL Database when only trying to insert one!

Let me know if you need to see any additional code -- Thanks!

**User Class**

```
class User{

protected static $table_name="users";
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;
public $email;

public static function find_all(){
    return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users");    
}

public static function find_by_id($id=0){
    global $database;
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}

public static function find_by_sql($sql=""){
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)){
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);  
    }
    return $object_array;
}

public static function authenticate($username="", $password=""){
    global $database;
    $username = $database->escape_value($username);
    $password = $database->escape_value($password);
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM users ";
    $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}

public function full_name(){
    if(isset($this->first_name) && isset($this->last_name)){
        return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;  
    } else {
        return "";  
    }
}

private static function instantiate($record){
    $object = new self;
    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)){
            $object->$attribute = $value;   
        }
    }
    return $object;
}

private function has_attribute($attribute){
    $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
}

public function create(){
    global $database;
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO users (";
    $sql .= "username, password, first_name, last_name, email";
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= $database->escape_value($this->username) ."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escape_value($this->password) ."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escape_value($this->first_name) ."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escape_value($this->last_name) ."', '";
    $sql .= $database->escape_value($this->email) ."')";
    if($database->query($sql)){
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**Database Class**

```
class MySQLDatabase{

private $connection;

function __construct(){
    $this->open_connection();   
}

public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Database Connection Failed: " .
             mysqli_connect_error() .
             " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }
}

public function close_connection(){
    if(isset($this->connection)){
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}

public function query($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    $this->confirm_query($result);
    return $result;
}

private function confirm_query($result){
    if(!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");  
    }
}

public function escape_value($string){      
    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
    return $escaped_string;
}

public function fetch_array($result_set){
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set); 
}

public function num_rows($result_set){
    return mysqli_num_rows($result_set);    
}

public function insert_id(){
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
}

public function affected_rows(){
    return mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection); 
}

}
```

**Instantiation**

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = "test";
$user->password = "testing";
$user->first_name = "Bob";
$user->last_name = "Smith";
$user->email = "bsmith@gmail.com";
$user->create();
```

Comment: If you're wanting to do OOP database interactions I highly suggest you look at PDO and parameterized queries

Comment: Noted, out of scope for the question though.

Comment: It is, but I don't see anything in the posted code that would insert five records.

Comment: Agreed. I see nothing in the code you've posted that looks like it would cause such a bug. Can you post more code around the creation of a new user?

Comment: What aren't you telling us?  There is nothing in the code you provided that will create 5 rows.   The actual code where you are creating users is something that probably is the culprit.

Comment: And also out of scope, but beware of SQL injection. In your `find_by_id` function, you're not sanitising input before executing it nor using prepared statements.

Comment: Hey Rob, that is literally all I am doing to create a user is that one set of instantiation above, prior to actually making it usable as part of an application (I was simply testing). @ your SQL injection, agreed I have quite a few validation procedures to add in.

Comment: Hey gview -- Literally all that makes up this application at this point, two class files, a database config file, a functions file that does an autoload at this point, and the one set of instantiation code above to test the classes

Comment: Are you using include() or require() and cross including scripts? If so replace it with include_once() or require_once()

Comment: Out of scope: your User class is doing too much.

Comment: Hey All -- Pulled the code out of architecture and noticed that it works as intended by only adding one row to db... problem is with the include vs require somewhere... in process of switching out all includes to require_once - Will keep posted -- good eye blokeish

Comment: Yes Mikey -- could extend user class into a database object... Just trying to get running at this point :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blokeish was correct, issue was around an include/require which was occurring in the framework prior to being defined.